# I don't understand why this is giving me a error

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I am trying to create a part of a program that will eventually simulate blackjack.

```
def getShuffleDeck():
    newDeck = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'] * 4
    shuffleDeck = []
    print(newDeck)
    deckPreshuffle = list(newDeck)
    shuffleDeck = random.shuffle(newDeck)
    return shuffleDeck


def dealCard(playingDeck):
    playDeck = []
    player1CardDealt = playDeck[0]
    print("Dealer gave you: " + playDeck[0])
    player2CardDealt = playDeck[1]
    print("Dealer is dealt a card.")

    playingDeck.remove(playerCardDealt)
    playingDeck.remove(dealerCardDealt)
    return (playerCardDealt, dealerCardDealt, playDeck)

# def cardValues(cardDealt):
dealCards = []
dealCards = (getShuffleDeck())
print(dealCards)


# print(dealtCard)

player1Card = dealCards
player2Card = dealCards[1]
currentDeck = dealCards[2]
print(player1Card)
print(player2Card)
```

the program is giving me a nonetype error. can someone please explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
playDeck = []
player1CardDealt = playDeck[0]
```

will always give you an error since you are trying to access the first element of an empty list ...

additionally

```
def getShuffleDeck():
    newDeck = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'] * 4
    shuffleDeck = []
    print(newDeck)
    deckPreshuffle = list(newDeck)
    shuffleDeck = random.shuffle(newDeck)
    return shuffleDeck
```

will always return None ... since `random.shuffle` shuffles the deck in place and does not return a value (Im pretty sure at least)

Comment: Ok, I see what I did wrong. Thanks for clearing everything up for me